# Can I build an iPad app using (html & css & jquery) In windows

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, ios, ipad

Can I build an iPad app using (html & css & jquery) In windows

I want to build a personal apps (Only for my iPad)

I don't want to put it in App Store.

Answer (score 4):

Build a HTML page which is enabled for use with iOS. Add a cache manifest and when you open it the first time add it to the Home screen. That's it.

- This is a good [tutorial](http://matt.might.net/articles/how-to-native-iphone-ipad-apps-in-javascript/).
- [Build your App online](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/13_tools_for_building_your_own_iphone_app.php)

Comment: On Windows this is your only option that I'm aware of. Xcode, for building and compiling native apps, is OS X only.

Answer (score 0):

You can build web apps for the iPad using those technologies.  Obviously, you will need to be connected to the web to use them.

You can also build apps locally in objective-c and install them on your development iPad if you don't want to go through the app store.  You just can't distribute them.